# Prolog - Append some elements form a list to another one

Tags: prolog

I need to append some elements from a list to another like this:

```
find_same(pt(1,1),pt(2,2),6,[slope(6,pt(3,3)),slope(6,pt(4,4)),slope(7,pt(3,2)),slope(9,pt(5,5))],NL).
```

result

```
NL=[pt(1,1),pt(2,2),pt(3,3),pt(4,4)]
```

I have tried using append but i have some problem, with this code:

```
find_same(_,_,_,[],_):-!.
find_same(pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya),R,Slopes,Nl):-X\=a,
    append(Nla,[pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya)],Nl),
    find_same(pt(a,a),pt(b,b),R,Slopes,Nla).
find_same(pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya),R,[slope(R,pt(Xs,Ys))|Ss],Nl):-X=a,
     append(Nla,[pt(Xs,Ys)],Nl),
     find_same(pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya),R,Ss,Nla).
find_same(_,_,R1,[slope(R2,_)|_],_):-R1\=R2,!.
```

because return me a lot of list.

then i tried with this other code:

```
find_same2(_,_,_,[],_):-!.
find_same2(pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya),R,Slopes,_):-X\=a,
           find_same2(pt(a,a),pt(b,b),R,Slopes,[pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya)]).
find_same2(pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya),R,[slope(R,pt(Xd,Yd))|Ss],[pt(Xd,Yd)|Nl]):-
           X=a,!,
           find_same2(pt(X,Y),pt(Xa,Ya),R,Ss,Nl).
find_same2(_,_,R1,[slope(R2,_)|_],_):-R1\=R2.
```

But it returns only false.

how can i solve this problem? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't care what the specific components of the points are, you can treat each point as a single variable. So instead of `pt(X, Y)` for example, just consider it `P`.

So you want to find the common points:

```
find_common(P1, P2, N, SlopeList, Result)
```

If you can create a sublist of elements from `SlopeList` which meet your criteria, then you can form `Result` by prepending the two existing points. If that sublist is called, `CommonPoints`, then your `Result` would just be `[P1, P2 | CommonPoints]`.

Now you only need to figure out how to determine `CommonPoints`. You can use `member/2` to do this. Consider:

```
member(slope(N, P), SlopeList)
```

This will succeed for each element of `SlopeList` that has an element `slope(N, P)`. To gather them together, you can use `findall/3`:

```
findall(P, member(slope(N, P), SlopeList), CommonPoints).
```

Those are all the pieces you need to solve your problem. You just have to put them together.